# "The app references non-public selector" when submitting SceneKit App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, scenekit, submission

I'm getting this warning message while validating the app for iTunes Connect. I think it says I'm using a private API but I'm pretty sure it isn't private.

Any ideas?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: pretty sure because of what? is the method publicly documented and not marked as deprecated either?

Comment: It is documented and not deprecated. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAction_Class/index.html

Comment: does the warning go away if you comment out all uses of the function? You should probably contact Apple support about this.

Comment: or, perhaps you have not properly set your app to run only on ios 8.0 and above? check deployment target, it should be 8.0 or higher.

Comment: that said you should be able to target any version and conditionally use SceneKit when running on 8.0+. Is SceneKit.framework marked as optional (weak linked) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the validation process. Please file a bug to Apple.

Comment: I have experienced this bug with the following SceneKit methods SCNAction fadeOpacityTo:duration:, rotateByX:y:z:duration, rotateToX:y:z:duration:shortestUnitArc:   - I have filed a bug report to apple.